# Excel function for searching/matching/pasting data from different tables

Tags: function, search, indexing, dataset, match

I have huge bank database from Bankscope which will be used in econometric analysis. I'm struggling how to associate bank statistics (table A, time period 9 years) with macroeconomic stats (table B, time period 9 years) from Eurostat.

**I'm searching for excel function which would search/match/paste values by conditions (year + country) from table B to table A.**

Illustrative example

[dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Rfom.png)

Thank you in advance

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C2 type :

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($H$2:$J$7,MATCH($B2,$G$2:$G$7,0),MATCH(C$1,$H$1:$J$1,0)),"")
```

then drag until E8 .

Comment: You're welcome. Appreciate if you can 'accept' the answer like [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) . It will remove this question from the 'unanswered' question list. ( :